# Lightning Component - Intermittent Long Loading Times

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I've created [this very same example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm?search_text=visualforce) in my org in order to test the new `lightning:datatable`. The SOQL query in the apex method is also limited to 10 records. Typically my requests finish within 2 seconds:

[image]

Although, occasionally (very random, sometimes every 5th request, other times I can't replicate it after 30 requests), it takes more than 15 seconds for the component to load:

[image]

I had a look at the debug logs and even with trace flags set to `FINEST`, it wouldn't show anything:

[image]

All I can see is `[EXTERNAL]Aura` taking 15 seconds to complete. The timeline shows this:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this (in particular on v41.0)? Are there any lightning settings or config that I'm missing which might help with this weird behaviour?

Comment: I believe that you already have following settings: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-components-performance-best-practices.html#settings

Comment: At first debugging was off and caching on. Then I switched debugging on to see what's going on. Tried switching the caching off too, same same... These settings seem to have no impact on this issue.

Comment: Yes. I am also facing the same issue. Initially, I thought i was missing something as i am not able to see the data immediately. Later i realized it is taking at the component level. Please update once you got some resolution.

Comment: Was anyone able to find the root cause of this behavior? I am facing the same issue now. The component was working fine so far.